# migrate magento 1.6 to 1.9.2

Tags: magento, migration, magento-1.9, magento-1.6

I need to migrate old magento store 1.6 to 1.9.2. Rather then messing up the running site I decided to do it at new server and change dns later. I have installed 1.9.2 at new host. installed new theme( old theme was not compatible). Copied all media files.I searched for possible options.
One possible solution is https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Manual+upgrade+using+a+fresh+install+and+new+database. 
I found a migration tool http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html but I am not sure whether it is only for 2.0 or it works for 1.9.2 too. I am php developer. I have worked for magento 3 years back.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a migration tool http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html but I am not sure whether it is only for 2.0 or it works for 1.9.2 too

The migration tool is for migrating to Magento 1.x to Magento 2. You don't need that tool to upgrade from 1.6 to 1.9.

The [first link](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Manual+upgrade+using+a+fresh+install+and+new+database) you posted should be all you need to upgrade. In short:

- Setup a new instance of Magneto 1.9 on the destination server

  - You don't need to run the installer or create a fresh database, you will import the database from the old site.
- Move your theme, extensions and media to the new site
- Export the database from the live site

  - Disable caching and compilation before exporting
- Import the database to the new site
- Navigate to the new site and wait for the upgrade process to complete.

You may also want to put the old site in maintenance mode before exporting the database. This will prevent updates to the old site, which will be lost when you update the domain to point to the new site.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to understand last 2 steps. import database from 1.6 to new database of 1.9? But both databases are not same. Navigate to site and wait for upgrade process. Upgrade 1.9?

Comment: @softcell When you setup the new server, all you need is the Magento 1.9 files. Copy the database from the old server and create a `app/etc/local.xml` file that uses that database on the new server.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused about it as the database for 1.6 is not the same as database for 1.9.2. Even number of tables are different.

Comment: @softcell The upgrade process will handle updating the database. When Magento is loading, it is going to detect that the database version is "lower" than the file version. This will trigger the update process. During the update process Magento will run the update scripts which will handle upgrading the database. Look in the sql directory of any module for an example.

Comment: Thanks. I got it now

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But now the site switched to default theme. I went to admin and changed the theme from there. Flushed  cache. Reindexed. But it is in default theme. Before updating the database, it was showing proper theme.

Comment: @softcell Were you working directly off of one of the default themes? The default themes are part of the Magento core and will be overwritten in an upgrade.

Comment: No. I had installed a new theme and changed the theme. But after upgrade, it switched back to default. Now even when I change from admin, it remains with the default theme.

Comment: @softcell I don't have enough details to figure out what is going on. You may want to create a separate question for that. Feel free to send me the link and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks. You helped me transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a fresh magento 1.9.2, then follow following steps to move all data from 1.6 to 1.9.x:

1) Take a backup of current database and current magento code.

2) Now put following folders from old magento to 1.9. You need to merge carefully if any existing folders or files exist in magento 1.9

- app/code/local
- app/code/community
- app/etc/modules
- media
- Your theme and package folders.
- Similarly in skin any theme and package folders that exist in old
  magento but not in new magento, copy them in new magento
  installation.
- Custom js files if any from js folder

3) Now go to app/etc/local.xml and configure db

4) If your old magento version like 1.6 does not support fromkey and new one does, any template you are using will need to be upgraded to use formkeys, otherwise your forms will not work

5) If you’re upgrading magento to version above 1.9.2.2, you’ll also have the set the Block/Variable permissions in admin.

For details visit the following link:

[Upgrade magento from old versions to 1.9.x](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=160)